# How to get values from disabled form controls in a form group?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I tried to initialize my new FormControl using form state object and I noticed then this control doesn't influence my form validation and it also disappear from FormGroup values.

```
this.userForm = new FormGroup({
  email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  firstName: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
  lastName: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
  role: new FormControl({value: 'MyValues', disabled: true},Validators.required),
 })
```

Now if I try to do:

```
this.userForm.value //email, firstName, lastName
```

Have someone encountered this issue ? Any solution ?
Angular version: 5.2.6

Comment: I'm not sure i understood. It seems fine to me. When i write `this.userForm = new FormGroup({
            email: new FormControl('test', Validators.required),
            firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            role: new FormControl({value: 'MyValues', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
        })
        console.log(this.userForm.value);`, I see my values.

Comment: @AlexandreAnnic yes, u understood fine. But it doesn't work, I also noticed that disabled controls can't be valid nor invalid because of their status (disabled)

Comment: disabled controls wont be returned by value or be considered on the validation of the form. If you want to print the role value, use `userForm.getRawValue()`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo thank you. It worked for me.

Comment: Added an answer as this could be useful for others

Comment: @OleksandrOleksiv consider to mark this as solved

Answer (score 127, accepted):

This is not an issue, is the expected behavior. If you'd like to include all values regardless of disabled status, use the following:

```
this.userForm.getRawValue()
```

Answer (score 10):

Thank you [@jota-toledo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394220/jota-toledo) for getting me 80% what I needed.

For those of you looking for a solution to the same problem but for nested forms I was able to solve by changing my usual

```
this.userForm.get('nestedForm').value
```

to

```
this.userForm.getRawValue().nestedForm
```

Answer (score 6):

If someone is looking for solution to get the disabled **FormControl** of **FormArray** in a **FormGroup**.

Try this -
`(this.formName.controls['formArrayName'] as FormGroup).getRawValue();`

Answer (score 3):

**TS** solution:

```
this.userForm.getRawValue()
```

**OR**

**HTML Only** solution:

```
<input formControlName="name" [readonly]="condition">
```

**OR**

**CSS Only** solution:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Html and Css solutions will block user to interact with input but Reactive form will get the value