# Angular FormArray getRawValue() At Index

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, disabled-input

Is there a way to get an item value using getRawValue() for FormArrays in Angular.

I have the code using `at(i).value` returning the value of the object at index "i".

```
var itemValue = (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('myList')).at(i).value;
```

As per @eper's answer in the post [How to get values from disabled form controls in a form group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675329/how-to-get-values-from-disabled-form-controls-in-a-form-group)

I accessed the raw value of the form array with the code below:

```
var itemRawValue = (<FormArray>this.myForm.getRawValue().mylist);
```

How can I get the raw value of the item at index "i"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

itemsRawValue is already an array. You can access the object using below code.

```
const index = 0;
var itemsRawValue = (<FormArray>this.myForm.getRawValue().mylist)[index];
```